# Can URL remain the same if migrating from Drupal?

Tags: urls

I would like to migrate from Drupal 6 to WordPress.

The article URL in Drupal is: `example.com/node/230`

If I migrate to WordPress, can the URL be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, but:

1. it might be hard if drupal mixes several types of content under the /node/ parent.
2. Those are not very SEO or even human freindly URLs so you might actually want to change them and just have a redirect from the old one to the new one.